# Doubt in uniform convergent sequence

Tags: uniform-convergence

Check that $$f_n(x)=\frac {x^n}{1+x^n}$$ where $x \in (0,1)$ is uniformly convergent or not?

My approach: using Mn test of uniformly convergent sequences $x_n=1-1/2n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ is belong to $(0,1)$

But

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x_n) \ne 0$$ implies that $f_n(x) $ is not uniformly convergent sequence in given domain.

Is my approach correct??

Any hint and solutions is well appricated.

Comment: Instead of $f_n(x_n) \ne 0$ you should say $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x_n) \ne 0$

Comment: This sequence is not uniformly convergent. First check that it converges to 0 pointwise and then for $n$ fixed, take the supremum over $x\in (0,1)$. You should be able to see that this is $1/2$, because of the function's behaviour near $x=1$.

Comment: @User It is pointwise converges to $0$ checked already but confused about uniformly or not

Comment: That's what I said. But for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\sup_{x\in (0,1)} |f_n(x)|=1/2$, hence it is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Since the sequence converges at the point $x=1$ as well, if there was uniform convergence in $(0,1)$ then there would be uniform convergence in $(0,1]$ as well. But that's clearly not the case, because the limit function is not continuous on the interval $(0,1]$.

Comment: @Mark  "Since the sequence converges at the point x=1
 as well, if there was uniform convergence in (0,1)
 then there would be uniform convergence in (0,1]
 as well."   I am getting confused with this statement can we include/exclude a point in the domain of convergence like $1$ in this particular question? Also In my sequential approach is it a valid argument Please clarify.

Comment: @Maths You want to prove there is no uniform convergence in $(0,1)$. If you assume by contradiction that there is uniform convergence, then there would be uniform convergence also in $(0,1]$. (if you are not sure why, try to prove it) So that's a valid argument. Of course, this is not the only possible solution. Your argument also looks fine, as long as you explain it correctly when you write a full solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am just a student so I hope my answer is correct but I think that your way of thinking is correct. In all the cases here a full answer that I hope will help you or other.

-First we need to find the function towards $f_n(x)$ p.w. converges.
$\forall x \in [0;1[ \Rightarrow  f_n(x) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} 0$ and for $f_n(1)=1/2, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

-Now [we know that](https://uel.unisciel.fr/mathematiques/suites_fonctions/suites_fonctions_ch01/co/apprendre_ch1_08.html#:%7E:text=Pour%20montrer%20que%20(%20)%20ne%20converge,vers%200%20lorsque%20tend%20vers%20.) in order to prove that a sequence of function $(f_n)$ is not uniformly convergent on $I=]0;1[$ we need to find  at least one sequence $(x_n) \in I$ s.t. $f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)$ doest not converge to $0$.
We choose $x_n=1-1/n \Rightarrow f(x_n)=0 $ as $0<x_n<1 \Rightarrow f(x_n) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} 0$ and $f_n(x_n)= \frac{(1-1/n)^n}{1+(1-1/n)^n}\underset{n \rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{1+e}$
Now by basic limit arithmetic rule we get that $(f_n(x_n)-f(x_n))\underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow} \frac{1}{1+e} \neq 0$.
*Rem:* when we use the known limit: $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n\underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow} \frac{1}{e}$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Although the pointwise limit is $f\equiv 0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=0, \quad \text{for all $x\in(0,1)$},
$$
Still
$$
f_n(2^{-1/n})=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Hence, for $\varepsilon=1/3$, there is no $N$, such that $|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$, for all $x\in (0,1)$.